# Rhandsontable conditional formatting- How to highlight rows based on specific attribute value?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I'd like to apply color highlighting for a entire row depending on a value and retain check boxes functionality of rhandsontable. In the simple example below, I'd like row 3 to be pink and row 4 to be green.

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame( bool = TRUE,val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

###Checkboxes not Present/Entire row not highlighted
rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE, width = 750, height = 300) %>%
  hot_cols(renderer = "
           function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
            if (value == 'C') {
           td.style.background = 'pink';
           } else if (value == 'D') {
           td.style.background = 'green';
           }
           }")

####Checkboxes Present
rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE, width = 750, height = 300)
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you use a NumericRenderer which tries to convert the applied columns to numeric. My solution may not be optimal, but it does the job.

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame( bool = TRUE,val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                 small = letters[1:10],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Text Renderer
text_renderer <- "
  function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    # This is the column which you want to check for coloring
    var col_value = instance.getData()[row][2]
    if (col_value == 'C') {
      td.style.background = 'pink';
    } else if (col_value == 'D') {
      td.style.background = 'green';
    }
  }"

# Renderer for the bool column
bool_renderer <- "
  function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.CheckboxRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    var col_value = instance.getData()[row][2]
    if (col_value == 'C') {
      td.style.background = 'pink';
    } else if (col_value == 'D') {
      td.style.background = 'green';
    }
  }
"
# Entire row highlighted and checkbox attribute preserved
rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE, width = 750, height = 300) %>%
  hot_col(col = c(2, 3, 4), renderer = text_renderer) %>%
  hot_col("bool", renderer = bool_renderer)
```

The trick is that you create two renderers:

- A CheckboxRenderer specifically for your bool column
- A TextRenderer for the remaining columns.

`instance.getData()[row][2]` retrieves the value of the big column at row index `row`. So the renderer checks for each row whether the condition in the if-statement is TRUE.

Cheers